# Cakephp 2.4.6 JsHelper / Ajax "id is not defined"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

```
<td class="process" id="<?php echo $process['Process']['id'] ?>">
    <?php echo $process['Process']['start']; ?> 
    <?php if (!is_null($process['Process']['end'])) : ?>
        - <?php echo $process['Process']['end']; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $process['InstallationEquipment']['Equipment']['name']; ?>
</td>

$this->Js->get(".process")->event('click', $this->JS->request(array(
  'controller'=>'lines',
  'action'=>'listed'), array(
    'update'=>'#conditions',
    'async' => true,
    'method' => 'post',
    'dataExpression'=>true,
    'data'=> '$(this).attr(id)'
  )));
```

Hi,

As you can see i try to load content when i click on a "process" but i got the same message which is "id is not defined" on the `'data'=> '$(this).attr(id)'` but I'm sure is set.

Someone can explain how do this in the good way ?

Sorry for my english and thank you for reading.

Comment: You are sure as in you checked the actual HTML and id is there?

Comment: Yes, I checked and I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your line:

```
'data'=> '$(this).attr(id)'
```

to:

```
'data'=> '{id: $(this).attr("id")}'
```

Comment: Thank you, the error disappear but the function in my controller get a empty request->data.